# I want to merge two XML file into single xml file

Tags: c#, xml, merge

I have a two xml file and want to merge into single xml file. The merged file should not have common nodes and if some node's ID matched but they have different characteristic then we have sum up there characteristics into merged xml file. Please provide me the source code for C# .net project.Keep in mind thatwe can have 2000 files for merging.

Comment: `"Please provide me the source code"` Please provide me with $100,000. Believe it or not, some people actually ***write*** code, instead of copy & pasting snippets they find on the internet.

Comment: This is not a code on demand site. Show your code and where you are stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps:

1. Parse each file into an `XDocument`
2. Apply your merge algorithm to the two `XDocuments` and produce a third, merged `XDocument`
3. Write the resulting `XDocument` to a xml file.

Voilà, job finished.